# How to add data to the CK editor dynamically at cusor point

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have implemented the CKeditor but have trouble adding data at specific points of the editor. I went through the CKeditor doc all the code contained the CKEDITOR keyword, so how and where can I apply this. like in this http://zkfiddle.org/sample/22fu1pr/4-Insert-text-at-cursor-for-CKEditor#source-1 but angular implementation

I have tried the id,

```
HTML
  <div class="row mb-3">
                        <form role="form" 
  #myForm="ngForm" accept-charset="UTF-8" novalidate>
                            <div 
   class="form-group has-feedback"

   [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': myckeditor.invalid && myckeditor.touched }">

  <ckeditor [(ngModel)]="mycontent"

   #myckeditor="ngModel"

   id = "myckeditor"

  name="myckeditor"

  required

  [config]="ckeConfig"

  debounce="500">

  </ckeditor>
                                <div 
  *ngIf="myckeditor.invalid && myckeditor.touched" class="help- 
  block">Required field.</div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary mr-2 ml-2" (click)="addValue()">CustomerNo</button>
                    </div>
 ts 
   export class AppComponent {
   name = 'ng2-ckeditor';
   ckeConfig: any;
   mycontent: string;
   log: string = '';
   @ViewChild("myckeditor") ckeditor: any;

    constructor() {
     this.mycontent = `<p>My html content</p>`;
   }

   ngOnInit() {
    this.ckeConfig = {
    allowedContent: false,
    extraPlugins: 'divarea',
    forcePasteAsPlainText: true
    };
  }

 public addValue(): void {
    this.CKEDITOR.instances['myckeditor'].setData('<p>This is the 
 editor data.</p>');
}

}
```

I want to be able to append values to the CKeditor dynamically with a button click or with a hyperlink.

Comment: grammar and spelling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#myckeditor="ngModel"` limits the functionality of the ckeditor so instead use  `#myckeditor` and on the `ts`  use `@ViewChild('ckeditor') public ckeditor: any;` to get access to the editor and simply do this `this.ckeditor.instance.insertText(temp);` to insert text to the cursor  pointer position.

https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/CKEditor-3.x/heres-how-insert-text-and-tags-cursor

Comment: I had tried with this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdp7d1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts i am getting Cannot read property 'insertText' of undefined error